# "GeorgeNotFound" 's MinecraftShocker plugin if you have this error: jSSC-2.8_x86_64.dll+0xb5db, how to fix

Tags: java, arduino-uno, firmata

Currently I am trying to copy "GeorgeNotFound" 's MinecraftShocker plugin from his Video (https://youtu.be/rCyJ-TFFxWA) *but i am getting this error which means no Arduino is found right?*

*I already checked the Arduino Uno is connected to "COM3" and I already have the Firmata installed on the Arduino.*

*I'm using Maven to add libraries.*

*I changed the jar i was using from slf4j-log4j12.jar to slf4j-jdk14.jar and now i get a different error.*

*Added text to indicate where it keeps failing.*

*Made all earlier Edits Italic for better readability.*

I am not using the `slf4j-jdk14.jar` anymore,
Instead I removed the dependencies of `org.scream3r:jssc:2.8.0` in `com.github.kurbatov:firmata4j:2.3.8` and istalled `io.github.java-native:jssc:2.9.2` separately (so it now doesn't use the 2.8.0 as default anymore, but instead is using the fixed 2.9.2 version ;) )
And voilà it's working

ERROR:

```java
Connecting...
Connected
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000007110b5db, pid=9764, tid=1144
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (15.0+36) (build 15+36-1562)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (15+36-1562, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jSSC-2.8_x86_64.dll+0xb5db]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Lucky 56\IdeaProjects\Shocker\hs_err_pid9764.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

Process finished with exit code 1
```

CODE:

```
package me.lucky56.shocker;

import org.firmata4j.IODevice;
import org.firmata4j.Pin;
import org.firmata4j.firmata.FirmataDevice;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Connecting...");
        IODevice device = new FirmataDevice("COM3");
        System.out.println("Connected");
        device.start();
        device.ensureInitializationIsDone();
        System.out.println("Connected Successfully");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            turnOn(device);
            System.out.println("On");
            Thread.sleep(250);
            System.out.println("Off");
            turnOff(device);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        device.stop();
    }

    static void turnOn(IODevice device)
    {
        try
        {
            device.getPin(7).setMode(Pin.Mode.OUTPUT);
            device.getPin(7).setValue(350);
            device.getPin(13).setMode(Pin.Mode.INPUT);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void turnOff(IODevice device)
    {
        try
        {
            device.getPin(7).setMode(Pin.Mode.INPUT);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: device.ensureInitializationIsDone(); problem is here

Comment: did you just read the Main.java:13 thingy ?
because in my program that line is: `IODevice device = new FirmataDevice("COM3");`

Comment: Not clear how you're managing libraries. Maven? Gradle? Or manually adding jar files to your project?

Comment: Maven, ill add it in the description thanks :)

Comment: Can you add the pom file to the question?

Comment: Actually, I don't know what's wrong with the new error, but I would suggest trying Java 11 instead of 15

Comment: where do I find that? sorry I'm "new" at this ;D

Comment: trying Java 11 now

Comment: Hmm. Try newer versions of this? https://github.com/java-native/jssc/releases

Comment: ok im trying now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not using the `slf4j-jdk14.jar` anymore,
Instead I removed the dependencies of `org.scream3r:jssc:2.8.0` in `com.github.kurbatov:firmata4j:2.3.8` and istalled `io.github.java-native:jssc:2.9.2` separately (so it now doesn't use the 2.8.0 as default anymore, but instead is using the fixed 2.9.2 version ;) )
And voilà it's working